# Pull another query in Webi

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am facing issue when using Result from another query in WebI. Version: 4.1 SP6

I need to use subquery which is not dependent on the outer query. When I use filter from the universe it was taking more time to execute. So, I created a dimension in the universe(IDT) and used it as a separate query in WebI. Then I am using the results from this query in the main query (another data provider) which is running faster. It's working faster and as expected.

The problem is: when I use the same prompt in the subquery(dimension used in another data provider) and the main query, the prompt is appearing twice (one prompt from subquery with blue arrow mark). When I discussed with another developer he informed that it's a SAP Bug.

Is there anyway I can hide the extra prompt that I am getting from another subquery, so that I can make the query to run faster by keeping subquery results separate?